# I've got problems pipenv installing django

Tags: django, installation

when I use pip as follows

```
pipenv install django
```

I get this error

> OSError: [WinError 1920] Systemet kan ikke få adgang til filen(System can't acces): 'C:\Users\Bruger\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe\Scripts.

I have tried numerous approaches to solve the issue such as

- move Python from C: drive to D: drive
- make a path to pipenv
- turned of virusprogram

This is an image of windows app folder

[image: p]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are encountering is related to the installation of Django using pipenv and appears to be caused by a permissions issue while accessing the Python executable file in the WindowsApps folder.

To resolve this issue, you have a few possible solutions:

Use Elevated Command Prompt (Run as Administrator):
Open an elevated Command Prompt by right-clicking on the Command Prompt icon and selecting "Run as administrator." Then, run the pipenv install django command again.

Install to a Virtual Environment in a Different Directory:
Instead of installing Django globally, you can create a virtual environment in a different directory and install Django there. Choose a directory where you have write access. Here's how to do it:

Open Command Prompt and navigate to the directory where you want to create the virtual

```
cd path/to/your/desired/directory
```

Create and activate a virtual environment:

```
python -m venv myenv
myenv\Scripts\activate
```

Now, you should see (myenv) at the beginning of your command prompt, indicating that the virtual environment is active.

Now, you can install Django using pipenv:

```
pip install django
```

Note: In a virtual environment, you use pip instead of pipenv.

Install Without Pipenv:
If you still encounter issues with pipenv, you can try installing Django using just pip without using pipenv:

```
pip install django
```

This will install Django globally, which might require administrator privileges. If you encounter permission issues, use the "Run as administrator" approach mentioned in the first solution.

Remember that using virtual environments is a recommended practice as it isolates project dependencies and prevents conflicts between different projects. If you still encounter issues, consider checking your Python installation and system permissions to ensure everything is set up correctly.

Comment: I tryied debug : 2
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. Information in the browser: {% load bootstrap5 %} {% bootstrap_css %} {% bootstrap_javascript %}
Learning Log 
Topics
{% block content%}{% endblock content %}

Comment: and cording to chatGPT 
It looks like you have the template tags from django-bootstrap5 correctly loaded in your template. The debug information you provided doesn't show any specific errors related to the {% load bootstrap5 %}, {% bootstrap_css %}, or {% bootstrap_javascript %} tags.

Since the code you've provided appears to be correct, it's possible that there might be other factors at play that are causing this issue.